# C sort array of strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort a array of strings in C. But it can't run. It seems I misuse qsort. Program crash in calling qsort. How can I fix my code. Should i use const char* [] instead of char[][]? Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 40
#define MIN 4
#define MAX 10

int generateRandomNumber(int low, int high)/*generate random number between low and high inclusive*/
{
    return rand() % (high + 1 - low) + low;
}

int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char* pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char* pb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa, pb);
}

int main()
{
    char words[N][MAX + 1];
    int i, j;
    int length;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        length = generateRandomNumber(MIN, MAX);
        for (j = 0; j < length; ++j)
        {
            words[i][j] = generateRandomNumber('a', 'z');
        }
        words[i][length] = '\0';
    }

    qsort(words, N, sizeof(char*), comp);

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by enabling all your compiler warnings, and by reading the manuals.

Comment: Can you give more information about the "crash" and errors?

Comment: 1) `sizeof(char*)` --> `sizeof(*words)` 2) `const char* pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char* pb = *(const char**)b;` --> `const char* pa = (const char*)a;
    const char* pb = (const char*)b;`

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++?

Comment: A pointer-to-pointer has no relation what-so-ever to a 2D array. That's why the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are not casting properly:

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char* pa = *(const char**)a;
    const char* pb = *(const char**)b;

    return strcmp(pa, pb);
}
```

should be:

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char* pa = (const char*)a;
    const char* pb = (const char*)b;

    return strcmp(pa, pb);
}
```

I do not know if there are other problems in your code, but when you cast a `void*` to a `const char**` you are sending the processor to access memory addresses that are bogus.

Answer (score 1):

You write your program as words has type `char *words[N]` (array of pointers to C-strings). But your type is `char words[N][MAX + 1]`. Its flat array, compiler can translate it to `char words[N * (MAX + 1)]`.

So, if you really want to save type of words then:

```
qsort(words, N, sizeof(*words), comp);

int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

Comment: I think it's better: `return strcmp((char *)a,(char *)b);`

Comment: @SergioFormiggini You forgot the `const` in both casts

Comment: Why? It's redundantly in C. More over, I would write: `qsort(words, N, (sizeof *words), (int (*)(void const *, void const *))strcmp);`

Comment: Doing some tests I've understand that the function comp shall contain: `return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);` and qsort may be: `qsort(words, sizeof(words)/sizeof(char *), sizeof(char *), comp);`

Comment: This would be right if words has type char *words[N].

Answer (score 0):

In your string compare function change

```
const char* pa = *(const char**)a;
const char* pb = *(const char**)b;
```

to

```
 const char* pa = (const char*)a;
 const char* pb = (const char*)b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* pa = *(const char**)a;
const char* pb = *(const char**)b;
```

should be:

```
const char* pa = (const char*)a;
const char* pb = (const char*)b;
```

and

```
qsort(words, N, sizeof(char*), comp);
```

should be:

```
qsort(words, N, sizeof(words[0]), comp);
```

the third parameter means the length of the array